# Is there any alternative to app.CreatePerOwinContext() method for .NET Core 6?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I'm migrating my ASP.NET MVC web application to .NET (Core) 6. While porting identity, I'm facing a blocker issue and I got stuck here.

Existing ASP.NET MVC app uses this code:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
}
```

I didn't find any reference on the internet that suggests a good way to do this in .NET Core.

`ApplicationUserManager` and `ApplicationSignInManager` also need to be created in .NET Core; in the ASP.NET MVC app, these classes are contained in the `App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs`.

How and where can I create these classes in .NET Core?

Thanks in advance

Comment: from .NET Core 3.0, OWIN middleware is no longer supported, Maybe you refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).